# Drive letter resets at reboot

Tags: windows, hard-drive

I have three hard drives: one SSD, and two HDDs. As the SSD is only 128 GB, I install programs on the E: drive. Now, recently the E: drive has begun to lose its assigned letter, and vanish from the system - until I enter `Disk Managemet` screen, and assigns its letter back. Also, if I try to shrink the volume in `Disk Management` an error pops up:

[image: The error]

I have tried to look through the Event Log, but I can't find anything related.

I think I have tried everything; `chkdsk /r` reported all is well, and I even tried to format both the E: drive, and the SSD, and reinstall Windows, with no luck. ¨

The drive is quite old, it's about 5 years old. Could it just be dying? The drive works just as expected after I have assigned a letter to it.

EDIT:

So, I downloaded SeaTools, and ran a few tests (only the basic ones, as the advances supposedly could erase data), and it seems to pass every single one.

Comment: It does indeed sound like the drive is starting to fail, if the problem exists, after you have reinstalled the operating system.

Comment: But if the drive is failing, isn't it weird that the it works perfectly just by assigning a letter to it?

Comment: I personally don't find that odd at all.  chkdsk /r not detecting a problem doesn't say much.  I would be more interested in what a tool like Seagate Tools indicates which performs low level tests and displays S.M.A.R.T data.